# Error when using AWS CLI commands in Git Bash - Found xterm, while expecting a Windows console

Tags: aws-cli, git-bash

When using AWS CLI commands in git Bash (windows environment) I get the error:

```
Found xterm, while expecting a Windows console. Maybe try to run this program using "winpty" or run it in cmd.exe instead. Or otherwise, in case of Cygwin, use the Python executable that is compiled for Cygwin.
```

Can you help me?

I tried to do the same with the shell and I was able to use it normally.

Comment: I was able to narrow down the problem by using winpty before the commands. It was more a matter of paying attention to the git bash message itself